# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for each()

Tags: php

Getting this error on my site for line 113, not sure why this is happening or what needs to be done to correct the code. See the snippet below.

```
    // Return the CDN object by name.
    // If a section is defined. Only returns the object if it exists in that section
    // if "Section" is not defined; returns an object if it exists in any section.
    // Returns FALSE if not found.
    public function CDN($name='',$section=''){
        if (empty($name)) return FALSE;
        else
        foreach ($this->CDNS as $CDN){
            if (!empty($section)) {
                if (stripos($name, $CDN->Name()) !== FALSE && ($CDN->Position() == $section)) return $CDN;
            }
            else
                if (stripos($name, $CDN->Name()) !== FALSE) return $CDN;

        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: The array $this->CDNS is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How do I correct this?

Comment: put something in it?

Comment: Add condition before foreach like: `if (! empty($this->CDNS)) { ...`

Comment: It's not that `$this->CDNS` *is empty*, it's that it's *not something that can be iterated.* So the question is: *what is it?!* And why is it that? And why isn't it something iterable, as you seem to expect?

Comment: you can use is_array($this->CDNS) to check for valid array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems `$this->CDNS` is empty. Do like below:

```
public function CDN($name='',$section=''){
    if (empty($name)) return FALSE;
    else
    {
     if(!empty($this->CDNS))
     {
    foreach ($this->CDNS as $CDN){
        if (!empty($section)) {
            if (stripos($name, $CDN->Name()) !== FALSE && ($CDN->Position() == $section)) return $CDN;
        }
        else
         if (stripos($name, $CDN->Name()) !== FALSE) return $CDN;

    }
    return FALSE;
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't `isset && !empty`; just `!empty` will do just fine.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: It's also not that "[the] array is empty", it's that *it isn't an array*. An empty array would not result in an error.

Comment: @sarkism You'r welcome. Don't forget to mark this as an answer, it might help other in future.